# Error parsing XML: mismatched tag AND Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Poids : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/poids"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Poids"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Taille : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taille"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Taille"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radio2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mètre"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centimètre"
        />
</RadioGroup>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/mega"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mega fonction !"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calcul"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculer l'IMC"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/raz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RAZ"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Résultat:"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Vous devez cliquer sur le bouton « Calculer l'IMC » pour obtenir un résultat."
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hi everyone, I try to make a view interface but I have those errors when I'm executing my code:

> -Error:(43) Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
>
> -Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Can anyone help me? Please I'm a beginner

Comment: your code doesn't have any error. try invalidate cache and restart the android studio

Comment: I checked your xml in my project, It's working perfect. Might be wrong in different xml.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

add / in line number 42 and delete  in line number 55

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Poids : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/poids"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Poids"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Taille : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taille"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Taille"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radio2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mètre"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centimètre"
        />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/mega"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mega fonction !"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calcul"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculer l'IMC"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/raz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RAZ"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Résultat:"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Vous devez cliquer sur le bouton « Calculer l'IMC » pour obtenir un résultat."
    />
</LinearLayout>
```